# Tensorflow: generate samples from a Multinomial distribution [Space efficient way?]

Tags: tensorflow, sampling, memory-efficient, multinomial

I have a quick question. How can I sample values in {0, 1} from a Multinomial distribution in TensorFlow? Actually I want a function that does what [numpy.multinomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) does.

Let's assume for example that I have a vector of counts and a vector of probabilities like this:

```py
counts = [5, 4, 3] # D in my code
probs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1] # v in my code
```

then I would like to return a matrix of size `(len(counts), len(probs)) = (3, 6)` whose sum over each rows = counts.

I looked at the TensorFlow code and I found a way to do what I want to do. Here is my piece of code:

```py
import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as ds

def multinomial_sampling(D, v):
    dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=D, probs=v)
    return  tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(dist._sample_n(1), 0 , False), [-1, v.shape[1]])
```

**Note**: I could just to an `tf.expand_dims` instead of a `tf.reshape`

The problem is that doing this is not space efficient and when my matrix is big enough TensorFlow just yells at me that I don't have enough memory because he is trying to create a matrix of size [1, 185929, 3390] where 3390 is the length of my probability vector.

So I wanted to do my own implementation of the multinomial sampling but I don't
know how to do that and I think there my idea is not efficient enough (in term of time complexity). Here is my skeleton:

```py
probsn = np.random.uniform(size=20)
probsn /= sum(probsn)

counts = tf.Variable([20, 12, 56, 3])
probs = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(probsn))

cprobs = tf.cumsum(probs)

out = tf.zeros([tf.shape(counts)[0], tf.shape(probs)[0]])
for i in counts.shape[0]:
    count = tf.gather(counts, i) # get each count
    sample = tf.gather(out, i) # get each row of out

   for j in range(count): # problem here count is a Tensor and not a int
       rdn_number = tf.random_uniform(1)
       for k, prob in enumerate(range(cprobs)): # problem doesn't work in TF
           if  tf.less(rdn_number, prob): 
               tf.scatter_add(out, [i, k], 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    r = sess.run(out)
    print(r)
```

this is a very naive algorithm. I think there might be a better way to decrease
the Time Complexity (with a kind of dictionay of range ? that maps to a range of float values the specific indice in the row ? Not sure if such a thing is possible but it would actually avoid me from iterating to find the indice in my row...).

Also, this implementation doesn't work as mentioned in the code because the **number** I'm iterating over are actually tensors.

Does somebody has a neat implementation of multinomial sampling in TensorFlow?

Comment: What about `tf.distributions.Multinomial`

Comment: I changed my code to use `dist.sample(1)` where `dist = tensorflow.contrib.distributions.Multinomial(total_count=D, probs=v)` but I still have the same memory usage

Comment: Actually I debugged it a bit and the fact that tensorflow is trying to create a tensor of size [1, 185929, 3390] comes from the fact that one of my count is actually: 185929 that is to say I need to sample 185929 from the same probability vector of size 3390. `dist.sample()` doesn't help so I need to do it on my own with a code that doesn't allocate big chunks. Yet I don't know how to do it in TensorFlow as the returned value of `tf.gather` are actually Tensor and not integer so I can't iterate over using `range` (as shown in my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently my problem is not a problem because I shouldn't have such a big number (185929). So I had edited some other piece of code. For the sake of completness if you want to sample a very large number and if you want to use `sample()`, you just cannot do that with:

```py
import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as ds

def multinomial_sampling(D, v):
    dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=D, probs=v)
    return  tf.reshape(dist.sample(), [-1, v.shape[1]])
```

if you don't have enough memory on your computer.

**Note**: I reshaped my tensor to the same shape so that TensorFlow won't
yell at me when I use the output of the `multinomial_sampling` function in a while loop. Without `tf.reshape`, in the `tf.while_loop`, Tensorflow crashes by saying that the I need to provide shape_invariants.

So you need to actually procede by batches. The idea is to sample a certain batch (like 1000) in a while loop and to decrease the counts at each iteration. Here is the piece of code I've made:

```py
probsn = np.random.uniform(size=30) 
probsn /= sum(probsn) # vector of probability of size 30 (sum of the vector = 1)

u = np.random.randint(2000, 3500, size=100) # define number of counts (vector of size 100 with int in 2000, 3500)
print(u) # should be the same as the output of print(np.sum(res, 1)) of the tf.Session()

counts = tf.Variable(u, dtype=tf.float32)
probs = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(probsn.astype(np.float32)))

import tensorflow.contrib.distributions as ds

dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=counts, probs=probs)

out = dist.sample()
samples = tf.zeros((tf.shape(counts)[0], tf.shape(probs)[0]))

def batch_multinomial(counts, probs, samples):
    batch_count = tf.minimum(1000., counts) # use a batch of 1000
    dist = ds.Multinomial(total_count=batch_count, probs=probs)
    samples += dist.sample()

    return counts - batch_count, probs, samples

_, _ , samples = tf.while_loop(lambda counts, *args: tf.equal(tf.reduce_all(tf.less(counts, 0.1)), False) , batch_multinomial, [counts, probs, samples])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(samples)
    print(res)
    print(np.sum(res, 1))
```